# How to Get the list of sub folders in a Directory that do not contain specific string

Tags: command-line

I need to list all the subfolder in a directory except thoughs that do not contain a particular string.

Example:
I have sub dir as

```
FileNov01
FileNov02
FileNov03
FileDec01
FileDec02
FileDec03
FileJan01
FileJan02
```

I want to list all the sub dir except which contain Dec
So the final output should be

```
FileNov01
FileNov02
FileNov03
FileJan01
FileJan02
```

I am trying to find the parameter for command shell.
Is there any switch to dir that exclude specific condition folder

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows

```
dir /b /ad * | findstr /v Dec
```